# I'm not joining the same room although I use the same Room ID socket.io": "^2.4.1"

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm trying to develop a video conference web app, when starting a new meeting and tries to join the same meeting from another browser I'm not able to join the same room instead, **I join another different room with the exact Room_ID, and both rooms still functioning.** I don't know which part I should upload, but I guess it might be from my sever.js [server] or my script.js [client] I also have a schema and auth but since I'm not receiving any ValidationError I assume they have connected correctly also my database(MongoDB) is connected correctly. my assumption is right, isn't it?
I looked to some other solution but most of them weren't helpful to my situation.

1- how can I join the same room?

2- if the code down below doesn't help I can update it just point me it's already a long one. (i can also share a GitHub repo I don't know if it's allowed) I'm a newbie, but I guess my question fits the criteria of "Asking a question" comment me if I need to improve something.
thanks.

`"socket.io": "^2.4.1"`
       `"uuid": "^8.1.0"`

I ran `console.lo()` on every variable after the `socket.on` and had the following :

After leaving 2nd room:

**RoomId:**  bf06ba93-ad99-43a4-bbae-1f8438df44ed

**PerrId:** e5def5cf-afff-40c9-8c5f-1b4fd6e66d82

**UserId:** 607220c9a947fe51247e4aba

**name:** test1

**audio:** true

**video:** true

After leaving orignal room:

**RoomId:**  bf06ba93-ad99-43a4-bbae-1f8438df44ed

**PeerId:**  607bc926-4cee-4326-b747-6548e0bb16d6

**UserId:** 60730e2032128f22a4d9293b

**name:** admin

**audio:**  true

**video:**  true

everything was the same except for the peerId and the userId and the name(userId and name are expected to differ) but I don't know if the peerId should differ, should it?  any help guys?

server.js [server]:

```
app.post("/join-room", (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(`/${req.body.room_id}`);
});

// user id get
app.get("/user", async (req, res) => {
  const roomData = await room.findOne({ roomId: req.query.room }).exec();
  res.json({
    user: await peerUser.findOne({ peerId: req.query.peer }).exec(),
    admin: roomData.admin,
  });
});

// video room
app.use("/", videoRoom);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("join-room", async (roomId, peerId, userId, name, audio, video) => {
    // add peer details
    await peerUser({
      peerId: peerId,
      name: name,
      audio: audio,
      video: video,
    }).save();
    // add room details
    var roomData = await room.findOne({ roomId: roomId }).exec();
    if (roomData == null) {
      await room({
        roomId: roomId,
        userId: userId,
        admin: peerId,
        count: 1,
      }).save();
      roomData = { count: 1 };
    } else if (roomData.userId == userId) {
      if (roomData.admin != peerId)
        await room.updateOne(
          { roomId: roomId },
          { admin: peerId, count: roomData.count + 1 }
        );
    } else
      await room.updateOne({ roomId: roomId }, { count: roomData.count + 1 });
    socket.join(roomId);
    socket
      .to(roomId)
      .broadcast.emit(
        "user-connected",
        peerId,
        name,
        audio,
        video,
        roomData.count + 1 // increase room members 
      );
```

script.js [client]:

```
 return toMatch.some((toMatchItem) => {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(toMatchItem);
  });
}
const socket = io("/");
const videoGrid = document.getElementById("video-grid");
const myPeer = new Peer(undefined, {
  path: "/peerjs",
  host: "/",
  port: "3000",
});
var Peer_ID;
const myVideo = document.createElement("video");
myVideo.muted = true;
var myVideoStream;
var myVideoTrack;
const peers = {};

navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
  .then((stream) => {
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: true,
      })
      .then((stream) => {
        myVideoStream = stream;
        myVideoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
        processStream(myVideoStream);
      });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: false,
      })
      .then((stream) => {
        myVideoStream = stream;
        processStream(myVideoStream);
      });
  });

socket.on("user-disconnected", (userId, count) => {
  if (peers[userId]) {
    peers[userId].close();
    delete peers[userId];
    changeCount(count);
  }
});

function processStream(stream) {
  addVideoStream(myVideo, myVideoStream, null, {
    name: name,
    audio: myVideoStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled,
    video: myVideoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled,
  });
  // recieve the others stream
  myPeer.on("call", (call) => {
    peers[call.peer] = call;
    call.answer(myVideoStream);
    const video = document.createElement("video");
    call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
      fetch(`/user?peer=${call.peer}&room=${ROOM_ID}`)
        .then((res) => {
          return res.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          addVideoStream(
            video,
            userVideoStream,
            call.peer,
            data.user,
            data.admin
          );
        });
    });
    call.on("close", () => {
      video.parentElement.remove();
    });
  });

  socket.on("user-connected", (userId, fname, audio, video, count) => {
    socket.emit("user-callback");
    connectToNewUser(userId, myVideoStream);
    changeCount(count);
  });
}
myPeer.on("open", (id) => {
  Peer_ID = id;
});
const changeCount = (count) => {
  const counter = document.getElementById("user-number");
  counter.innerHTML = count;
};
function connectToNewUser(userId, stream) {
  // set others peerid and send my stream
  const call = myPeer.call(userId, stream);
  const video = document.createElement("video");
  call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
    fetch(`/user?peer=${call.peer}&room=${ROOM_ID}`)
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        addVideoStream(
          video,
          userVideoStream,
          call.peer,
          data.user,
          data.admin
        );
      });
  });
  call.on("close", () => {
    video.parentElement.remove();
  });
  peers[userId] = call;
}
```

Comment: Hi @SamTheDemon, on the socket.on("join-room") callback I saw that you only use `socket.join` on the `else` part of code, Idk if you are calling it twice but on the `if` and `else if ` statements doesn't really have `socket.join` which they should have :)

Comment: @halilcakar just tired it and still no changes

Comment: Well, in the join-room callback no matter what you should join that socket instance to room. So when you emit something to that room that should recieve. Please then ckeck up your logic. Hopefully you can figure it out =)